# Neo4J - take results from one of two MATCH queries depending on property value

Tags: graph, neo4j, properties, match

I want to be able to be able to execute a specific `MATCH` statement based on the result of an ID that is passed in, and ignore the other `MATCH` statement.

Say the ID passed is `2`. I assume that because it has run the first query and not matched on anything, it is returning n2 as NULL and not going to the second MATCH statement. I might be wrong. How can I solve my problem? Any help would be great.

```
MATCH (n: nodeA)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n {id = 1})-[r]-(n2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n {id = 2})--(n2)
WITH n2
RETURN n2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer...

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n0:nodeA {id: 1})-[r]-(n2)
WITH collect(n2) AS first_match
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1:nodeA {id: 2})--(n2)
RETURN first_match + collect(n2) AS matches
```

You could just do two optional matches and return the union of the two result sets.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:nodeA {id: 1})-[r]-(n2)
RETURN n2
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:nodeA {id: 2})--(n2)
RETURN n2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I must only use one query, and therefore cannot have two `RETURN` statements.

Comment: ok. So you can't handle a NULL in the instance when the other query does not match?

Comment: If neither of the statements match a node, then I handle that elsewhere, but when I comment out the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` and run the query, the result that I want from the second statement is actually returned. When both statements are left in the query, it must be using the first statements NULL result, and ignores the second statement, therefore not returning the result from the DB.

If the entire query doesn't return a node, that's fine, but I know for a fact that the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` statement does when it's on it's own, but doesn't when the first statement is included.

Comment: you are using the same identifier `n` in both optional matches so only one can win. I provided an alternate possibility now that I think i understand better. The assumtion here is that the id will only match one or the other and not both.

Comment: Your updated solution works. It seems so simple now that I'm aware of it, but sometimes that's just the way it is. Thank you!

Comment: yeah - absolutely. i could see you were poking around the edges of what is possible and being oh so close to getting it